# Custom Field Tag Style List

Tags: joomla-3.x, mysql, database, custom-field, contact

Joomla 3.9.11

I have created an SQL custom field for my joomla contacts called `location`, this allows me to assign a location to my contacts.

The SQL simply selects `location_name` from a custom db table called `locations`. The custom field works as expected, and I am presented with a pre-populated list of locations when adding or editing a contact.

The trouble is, some of my contacts have **two** locations. Using this default custom field only allows me to assign **one** location.

I'm thinking I probably need a tag style custom field so that when I click the input, I am presented with a list of locations and I can select one or more.

Something like the `User Groups` field in [this image](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/YE7InInG8kz35uZq5EBt6ruGwnXWlqtwnl8uvdBDiwhONSq-sdC2etnhwa16dp94-D9P5OIlV_ttUfbFoTyTC4--3L6czUq7NC6AEjXPNEXutYqCKYmRZiFtgxgVGyipzy5pQmJb). However instead of being able to select user groups, I need to be able to select locations from my db table.

It's not necessary to be able to add to this list of tags from the input, just select them.

Is this possible, if so, how?

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that it's already an option!

Just select **Multiple: Yes** in the field options;

> Multiple : if set to "No" the field will allow the selection of a
>   single group of users, if set to "Yes" it will be possible to select
>   multiple groups of users.